# ImageView is animating under other imageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have Gridview with some pictures in. When pic is clicked scale animation starts but picture is scaled under other pictures and they are covering scaled picture. How to bring to front animation?

Any clues? 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `bringToFront()` on the view, either before or at the start of the animation.

Comment: That is ok, but i had an weard thing. After animation, pictures in gridview were in different order each time after animation process. setAdapter to gridview after animation helped :)

Comment: instead of setAdapter , consider updating the order in the new data , and use notifyDatasetChanged() .

Answer (score 0):

Calling bringToFront() changes the ordering in the GridView.  Try creating an ImageView with an image of the view you want to animate and animate that instead.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(view.getWidth() , view.getHeight());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    rootview.addView(imageView);
```

Add an animation listener to your animation and remove the ImageView at the end of the animation.